# eas.json variable override mechanism

Tags: expo, eas

How does overriding variables in expo work?

Hi I have a quick question:

I have created my eas.json file

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "base": {
      "node": "20.10.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.19",
      "android": {
        "image": "latest",
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "android",
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "http://10.0.2.2:8001"
        }
      },
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest",
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios",
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "http://localhost:8001"
        }
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "base",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "development"
      },
      "android": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "withoutCredentials": true
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "extends": "base",
      "channel": "staging",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "staging",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "https://staging.my-app.app/"
      },
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "extends": "base",
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "production",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "my-app.app"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

after running `eas build -p android --profile staging` on expo.dev I see my build listed with env var:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX2QD.png)

The value passed to build is http://10.0.2.2:8001 while expected was https://staging.my-app.app/.

How do I fix this? Is this possible? Do per platform env vars have to be overriden per platform also?

[EDIT]

This approach worked. However I think that this is counterintuitive and env defined directly under profile should indeed override per platform env from inherited profile

```
"staging": {
      "extends": "base",
      "channel": "staging",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "staging"
      },
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "env": {
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "https://staging.my-app.app/"
        }
      },
      "ios": {
        "env": {
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_BASE_URI": "https://staging.my-app.app/"
        }
      }
    }
```